# Grails GORM (Hibernate) query

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to do the below sql statement in GORM

```
select * from table1 where table1.x not in
      (select x from table 2 where y='something');
```

so, I have two tables, and needs to find the entries from table 1 which are not in table 2. In Grails

```
def xx= table2.findByY('something')
    def c = table1.createCriteria()
    def result= c.list {
      not (
        in('x', xx)
    )
}
```

the syntax is wrong, and I'm not sure how to simulate ***not in***  sql logic.

As a learning point, if someone can also tell me why minus (-) operator in grails/groovy doesn't work with list. I tried getting x and y seperately, and doing x.minus(y), but it doesn't change the list. I saw an explanation at [Groovy on Grails list - not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754576/groovy-on-grails-list-not-working) , but I would expect the list defined are local.

thank you so much.

Comment: I saw how to use HQL queries at http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+Querying, but prefer to know the criteria syntax. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, I'm just learning GORM myself, but one thing I see is that *in* is a reserved word in groovy and so needs to be escaped as *'in'*

Comment: You are right that in is a keyword, but I couldn't escape as mentioned. I used Restrictions.in (import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions), and the syntax was ok. still i couldn't get the logic work. I think there is an 'add' keyword to join in and not, but couldn't get it to work. hope someone would point me to the right direction. thanks for ur help

Answer (score 2):

Ok.. got to work.. anyone interested..

Stephen was right, you have to escape in with 'in', as it is a reserved word. the syntax is.

```
def c = table1.createCriteria()
    def result= c.list {
      not {
        'in'("x", xx)
//xx could be a list, array etc. eg: [1,2,3]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since  Grails 2.4 , you can write this query as a single query using a subquery  via [`notIn`](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/api/org/grails/datastore/mapping/query/Query.NotIn.html) & `DetachedCriteria(where)`:

& we have [two syntax](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/api/org/grails/orm/hibernate/query/AbstractHibernateCriteriaBuilder.html#notIn(java.lang.String,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) :

```
@java.lang.Override public Criteria notIn(java.lang.String propertyName, QueryableCriteria<?> subquery)

@java.lang.Override public Criteria notIn(java.lang.String propertyName, groovy.lang.Closure<?> subquery)
```

For your case , following should works:

```
def c = Tabl1.createCriteria().list {
              notIn 'x',Table2.where { eq('y','something') }.projections {
                     property 'x'
                     }.list()
    }
```